# stop postback for RadEditor with spellcheck

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor

When I use a RadEditor I want to enable the editor's spell check (working thus far). After a spell check the user can either click on the radmodule (toolbar thing) to either "finish spellcheck" or "cancel." Which is all fine and dandy except the "finish" button causes a postback!! I don't want that at this point!! "cancel" more or less does what I want to happen - I mostly just want a "done" or a way to stop the postback. Does anyone have any clues?

I've tried an Update panel but that just grays out the text area after it does the update.

Comment: did you just change my tags? I'm confused

Comment: yes, i retagged so you'll have a better chance at getting an answer.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a flop :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its cause we have a relatively old version of Rad now... Talked to my boss about buying new licenses..

Answer (score 0):

The "finish" button should not do a postback - verify this by going to the Telerik online demos - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx If it does postback, then there is a problem with some JS code on the page or some customization you did on the editor. Try starting with a blank editor page in your project and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: I see - I get the feeling my company's license is for an older version (at least it looks older). I wonder if that would be causing it(?) Do you have any suggestions for what might be causing it, or what to look for? - I'm obviously using ASP (C#) with a hefty set of jQuery stuff and a little standard javascript here n there.  I'm not sure I know how I could *accidentally* cause a postback from javascript, so I'm thinking codebehind, but I don't often explicitly refer to the control often.

Comment: Quick update on my conditions: I tested the javascript theory by removing all script references from the aspx file and still getting a postback and as far as I can see there are virtually no references to the radedtior in the codebehind either so I'm thoroughly lost.

Comment: I think the older version could be a problem only if it is more than a year old and you are testing in newer browser versions (Chrome, IE 8). If you are showing the editor dynamically (e.g. with jQuery), see if it will work when it is visible from the start and you don't show it with JS code. If this does not help, I think the only way out is for you to go to Telerik's forums or open a support ticket with them.